# Tiingo Data Reader

Tags: python, tiingo

I was developing a price prediction model that requires Tiingo but there seems to be problem in the API authentification. I used the OS access the Tiingo API.

```
`

api_key =os.environ.get('TIINGO_API_KEY')
    df=pdr.get_data_tiingo('AAPL',api_key)
    df=pd.read_csv('AAPL.csv')
    print(df.tail())
```

The error I got looks like:

```
    ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_9920/1017009006.py in <module>
      1 api_key =os.environ.get('TIINGO_API_KEY')
----> 2 df=pdr.get_data_tiingo('AAPL',api_key)
      3 df=pd.read_csv('AAPL.csv')
      4 print(df.tail())

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py in get_data_tiingo(*args, **kwargs)
    118 
    119 def get_data_tiingo(*args, **kwargs):
--> 120     return TiingoDailyReader(*args, **kwargs).read()
    121 
    122 

    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\tiingo.py in __init__(self, symbols, start, end, retry_count, pause, timeout, session, freq, api_key)
        181             api_key = os.getenv("TIINGO_API_KEY")
        182         if not api_key or not isinstance(api_key, str):
    --> 183             raise ValueError(
        184                 "The tiingo API key must be provided either "
        185                 "through the api_key variable or through the "
    
    ValueError: The tiingo API key must be provided either through the api_key variable or through the environmental variable TIINGO_API_KEY.
```

Any assistance is **highly** appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It seems api_key is coming as None. You should check that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33087826)